# Why is Δt constant in phase shift measurement?

Tags: measurement, delay, phase, bode-plot, time

I would like to ask for some help with phase shift plotting. To be precise, with time delay between two waveforms.

I am measuring two currents using an oscilloscope.

- channel A (blue) is my current clamp.
- channel B (red) is my shunt resistor, plugged into the wire supplying current to the clamp.

I use formula: angle = 360 * f * Δt. I noticed that regardless of frequency, Δt is almost constant (small fluctuation perhaps due to measurement error). Could anyone explain why is Δt a constant?

Overall, I got Bode plot of phase angle vs. frequency that looks sensible. However, I would “expect” Δt to change with frequency.

[image]

f=1 kHz, Δt=6 us;

---

[image]

f=10 kHz Δt=6.2 us;

---

[image: Phase]

Phase

---

[image: Magnitude]

Magnitude

Comment: possibly useful search term : group delay

Comment: It's a pretty common occurance when looking at the input and output of a 2nd order low pass filter with a zeta of 0.8660 or thereabouts. The current clamp will certainly have some inductance components and the oscilloscope will present a capacitance that could produce the "right" conditions with the burden resistor.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for nice analysis I will look into it!

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you. It crossed my mind as immediately thought of Bessel filter and it's behaviour.

Comment: @Wintermute You're in the right area. The clamp is an inductive device and, combined with other impedances (strays, meter impedance) will form a filter. Characteristic is unlikely to be Bessel except by happy accident, but group delay may be close enough to constant over the frequencies you are interested in.

Comment: Why don't you show the bode plot?

Comment: @Andyaka I added the bode plot.

Comment: Bode plot = Bode magnitude plot + Bode phase plot. Also, that bode magnitude plot doesn't tally with the earlier screen shots i.e. at 10 kHz the response should be more than 20 dB down i.e. you have an anomaly.

Comment: @Andyaka I added phase and magnitude. Regarding oscillogram gain and bode plot gain. I was using a multiple turn coil (20 turns) to “boost” my current from the signal generator. To avoid any issues due to inductance when I created new bode plots (attached above) I used a single wire and an amplifier. I adjusted the signal strength to always source 1A peak from the amplifier. Therefore my clamp current is normalised in respect to a source (amp).

Comment: Are the bode plots representative of the original waveforms you showed? It sounds like they are not? They need to be for exactly the same setup or I'm just wasting my time.

Comment: @Andyaka Apologies. Now bode plot and oscillograms correspond to each other. Previously I uploaded bode plots for single wire set up and forgot to update oscillograms.

Comment: OK, if it is how it looks then up to about 70% of the 3 dB point I would expect the phase shift to approximately linearly increase as frequency rises. It looks like a 2nd order filter given that the phase change doesn't converge to 90 degrees and probably converges to 180 degrees at HF. That means there will be a near-constant time delay for up to about 70% of the 3 dB frequency (circa 50 kHz) or about 30 kHz.